# Why public-law tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Do we need [public-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-law), when we already got [constitutional-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constitutional-law), [administrative-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/administrative-law), [criminal-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/criminal-law)? Plz see [chart below](https://www.srdlawnotes.com/2017/08/classification-of-law-with-help-of.html).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Yes

1. [public-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-law) is not a synonym of any of the others - indeed, your chart shows they are distinct and that the others are a subset of it.
2. Tags are free.